# How can I pass parameter correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, graphql, parameter-passing

```
const root = {
    user: (id) => {
        console.log("returning object " + JSON.stringify(id.id) + " " + JSON.stringify(storage.select("users", id.id)))
        return storage.select("users", id.id)
    }
}
```

I want to call the arrow function in `root.user` but I think I can't pass the parameter correctly, so I tried this --> `let user = root.user('101')`
and on the console I got this -->

returning object undefined

```
[{"firstName":"Gokhan","lastName":"Coskun","login":"gcoskun","id":101}]
{"firstName":"George","lastName":"Clooney","login":"gclooney"}
[{"firstName":"Gokhan","lastName":"Coskun","login":"gcoskun","id":101}]
```

I wanted the user with the id 101 get returned and got instead all of the users returned.

Comment: what is storage? can you give examples of it, please?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing `id.id` but passing a `string`? You either pass an object with an `id` prop (`root.user({ id: '101' })`) or replace `id.id` with simply `id`.

Also, it looks like the `id` fields in your user objects are of type `number`, while you are passing a `string`, so depending on the logic inside `storage.select` you might have to change that.

Passing a `number` `id`:

```js
// Just mocking it for the example:
const storage = {
  select(key, id) {
    return [
      { firstName: 'Gokhan', lastName: 'Coskun', login: 'gcoskun', id: 101 },
      { firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Clooney', login: 'gclooney' }, 
      { firstName: 'Gokhan', lastName: 'Coskun', login: 'gcoskun', id: 101 },
      // Depending on the logic here, these types need to match.
      // Using == instead of === so that it's not required here.
    ].filter(user => user.id == id)
  },
};

const root = {
  user: (id) => {
      console.log(`ID = ${ id }`);
      
      // We make sure we only return a single user or null if there isn't one:
      return storage.select('users', id)[0] || null;
  },
};


const user = root.user('101');

console.log(user);
```

Passing an `object` with an `id` prop of type `number`:

```js
// Just mocking it for the example:
const storage = {
  select(key, id) {
    return [
      { firstName: 'Gokhan', lastName: 'Coskun', login: 'gcoskun', id: 101 },
      { firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Clooney', login: 'gclooney' }, 
      { firstName: 'Gokhan', lastName: 'Coskun', login: 'gcoskun', id: 101 },
      // Depending on the logic here, these types need to match.
      // Using == instead of === so that it's not required here.
    ].filter(user => user.id == id);
  },
};

const root = {
  user: (query) => {
      console.log(`ID = ${ query.id }`);
      
      // We make sure we only return a single user or null if there isn't one:
      return storage.select('users', query.id)[0] || null;
  },
};

const user = root.user({ id: '101' });

console.log(user);
```

Comment: '101' is a string
{id: '101'} is a object that has an attribute id

Comment: @Jackstine In that case you can't call that function as `root.user('101')`, you need to pass in an `object` with an `id` prop on it, just like in the second example: ``root.user({ id: '101' })``